# Why don't I receive signal and status for WiFi using QSystemNetworkInformation

Tags: qt, qt4, symbian, nokia

I wrote a piece of software which does nothing else than reading network status and signal strength for each network mode (gsm, wlan (wifi), bluetooth, ...) on my device (Nokia E51) and printing it out.

My test device is connected to bluetooth, wlan (wifi) and 3G (wcdma), but it's only able to give me the signal strength of 3G (and also returns the correct name of my carrier). for wlan and bluetooth it gives me the undefined state und isn't able to read any signal strenght. But I am able to receive the IP address of the network I'm connected via wlan.

All I do is:

```
QSystemNetworkInformation::networkSignalStrength(QSystemNetworkInformation::WlanMode);
```

and calling the method for the network status.

As I said, it works flawless for 3G.

Any ideas? Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0):

After an SDK update, everything works fine without any code changes. So the problem wasn't in the coede, but in the QtMobility backend.